# jQuery scrolling down on click of an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a very long HTML page with content. What I am trying to achieve is when someone clicks a menu item in the header, the page should scroll down to an anchor element. I have try many things with no luck. I don't know JavaScript. This is what I tried:

_header.html.erb

```
<div class="header_pad">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="/">The Investors' Club</a></h1>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="left">
          <li><a id="result" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

application.js

```
 function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("#result").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('contact');
});
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="contact">
    <%= image_tag("contact_us.png", :alt => "Forex Investment Contact") %></br>
    <p class="small-11 small-centered columns">
        Skype is free and more convenient, give us a call or send us an email if you happen to have some questions. We will
        be glad to hear from you. 
        </br>
        <%= image_tag("skype.png", :alt => "skype") %> OR 
        <b>100forexinvestors@gmail.com</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

Live page: https://infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com
So I want it that when I click "Contact" in the header, it scrolls smoothly all the way down to the Contact anchor down below the page. Any help?

EDIT:
I got it to work with the js I posted as an answer. However. If I click on the back button and click another link, the animation doesn't work anymore till I reload the page. Looks like the javascript loads just once. How do I eliminate that?

Comment: in href="#contact" `<a id="result" href="#contact">Contact</a>` and in contact section use `<div id="contact">...</div>`

Comment: OK. I got to this stage but the scroll down effect doesn't work. It just jumps to the anchor, no effect. But the smooth scroll down is what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I got it to work with this piece of js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash;
      var $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have typo `<a name"test"></a>`. Try change it to `<a name="test"></a>`

**EDIT**

Since the question edited, this is the example for `application.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.top-bar-section a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var eid = $(this).attr('href');
    var top = $(eid).offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

Make sure the anchor `href` and target `id` is equal. E.g: `<a href="#contact">` for `<div id="contact">`

Comment: I edited the code. But as you can see here: https://infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com the smooth scroll is not happening.

Comment: I've test it by running your `application.js` script before posting comment and get working.

Comment: I edited my answer again. The js seems to load just once.

Answer (score 0):

this might help,

```
    function scrollToAnchor(aid){
var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},500);
```

Pass "time" as the second argument to the animate function. It should navigate to the target location in that much amount of "time". Thus helping smooth transition.

Comment: You can increase the time mentioned to say, 1000 for 1 second, 1500 for 1.5 seconds, so on and so forth depending on your requirement.

Comment: great :) don't overload it with 'swing' and other stuffs until and unless it's an utter necessity as this increases overheads on the UI side.. just the "time" parameter can give you a smooth transition. All the best! 
Also, you can upvote the answer if u feel it helped ;)